# niftynet multi-class 3D segmentation with dense vnet

Tags: image-segmentation, niftynet

Neural network newbie here. I've been testing Niftynet and achieved decent single-class 3D segmentation predictions on an own MRI data set with dense_vnet. However, I ran out of luck when I tried to add a second label. The network seems to spot the correct organs but can't get rid of additional artifacts as if it cannot get out of a local minimum or it doesn't have enough degrees of freedom or something. [This is one of the better looking prediction slices which does show some correct labels but also additional noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nutzr.gif).

Why would a single-class segmentation work better than a multi-class  segmentation? Is it even reasonable to expect good multi-class 3D segmentation results out of DenseVnet? If yes, is there a specific approach to improve the results?

P.S.
Niftynet's site refers to stackoverflow for general questions.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, DenseVnet does handle [multi-class segmentation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6076994/) okay. They have provided a [ready model](https://cmiclab.cs.ucl.ac.uk/CMIC/NiftyNetExampleServer/blob/master/dense_vnet_abdominal_ct_model_zoo.md) with a Dice loss extension. It worked with my MRI data without any pre-processing even though it's been designed for CT images and Hounsfield units.

Comment: Somewhat disappointed that none of the niftynet people have replied for over a week. Just  a simple sentence like "try different learning rates" would do. No wonder their github gets flooded with general questions.